# Keyboard shortcuts in EDMX designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, edmx-designer

I was wondering if there is a set of keyboard shortcuts to create/reorder/rename properties or entities in the EDMX designer of VS 2013?

Do you know of any? Is there a way to make them? I hate using the mouse when I can do the same with keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Although the context menu does not show it, you can use

1. F2 = Rename property
2. Select a property and then hit `Enter` to add new properties.

PS: My keyboard was mapped to Visual C# 2005 mapping scheme.

In addition you can add keyboard shortcuts to a lot of the actions you can take. To do this

1. Select `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard'.
2. Enter `Entity` in the `Show commands containing:`
3. Select the command you want from the list.
4. Select `ADO.NET Entity Data Model Design` in the `Use New shortcut in:`
5. Select your shortcut key.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great detailed answer!